# getting type T from IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

is there a way to retrieve type `T` from `IEnumerable<T>` through reflection?

e.g.

i have a variable `IEnumerable<Child>` info; i want to retrieve Child's type through reflection

Comment: In what context? What's this IEnumerable<T>? Is it an object instance sent as an argument? Or what?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<T> myEnumerable;
Type type = myEnumerable.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Thusly,

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();
Console.WriteLine(strings.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
```

prints `System.String`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) for `Type.GetGenericArguments`.

**Edit:** I believe this will address the concerns in the comments:

```
// returns an enumeration of T where o : IEnumerable<T>
public IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericIEnumerables(object o) {
    return o.GetType()
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType
                && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
}
```

Some objects implement more than one generic `IEnumerable` so it is necessary to return an enumeration of them.

**Edit:** Although, I have to say, it's a terrible idea for a class to implement `IEnumerable<T>` for more than one `T`.

Comment: Or even worse write a method with yield returns and try to call GetType on a variable created with this method. It will tell you that it is not event a generic type. So basically there is no universal way to get T given an instance variable of type IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Or try with class MyClass : IEnumerable<int> {}. This class doesn't have a generic interface.

Comment: Why would anyone ever resort to getting the generic arguments and then grabbing the type from its indexer?  That's just asking for disaster, especially when the language supports typeof(T) like @amsprich suggests in his/her answer, which can also be used with either a generic or a known type...

Comment: This fails miserably when used with linq queries - the first generic argument of a WhereSelectEnumerableIterator is *not*.  You're getting the generic argument of the underlying object, not the interface itself.

Comment: myEnumerable.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] gives you the FullName property which tells you the namespace.classname . If you are looking only for the class name use myEnumerable.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].Name

Comment: This fails when your using an array, which does cast to IEnumerable

Comment: For arrays, you can you GetType().GetElementType()

Answer (score 42):

I'd just make an extension method. This worked with everything I threw at it.

```
public static Type GetItemType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Comment: It won't work if your compile time reference is just of type object.

Answer (score 36):

I had a similar problem. The selected answer works for actual instances.
In my case I had only a type (from a `PropertyInfo`).

The selected answer fails when the type itself is `typeof(IEnumerable<T>)` not an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`.

For this case the following works:

```
public static Type GetAnyElementType(Type type)
{
   // Type is Array
   // short-circuit if you expect lots of arrays 
   if (type.IsArray)
      return type.GetElementType();

   // type is IEnumerable<T>;
   if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IEnumerable<>))
      return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

   // type implements/extends IEnumerable<T>;
   var enumType = type.GetInterfaces()
                           .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && 
                                  t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                           .Select(t => t.GenericTypeArguments[0]).FirstOrDefault();
   return enumType ?? type;
}
```

Comment: Saved my day. For my case, I added a separate if statement to handle strings since it implements IEnumerable<char>

Comment: `Type.GenericTypeArguments` - only for dotNet FrameWork version >= 4.5.
Otherwise - use `Type.GetGenericArguments` instead.

Answer (score 21):

If you know the `IEnumerable<T>` (via generics), then just `typeof(T)` should work. Otherwise (for `object`, or the non-generic `IEnumerable`), check the interfaces implemented:

```
        object obj = new string[] { "abc", "def" };
        Type type = null;
        foreach (Type iType in obj.GetType().GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (iType.IsGenericType && iType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            {
                type = iType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (type != null) Console.WriteLine(type);
```

Comment: Some objects implement more than one generic IEnumerable.

Comment: @Jason - and in those cases, the question of "find the T" is already a dubious question; I can't do anything about that...

Comment: One small gotcha for anyone trying to use this with a `Type type` parameter rather than an `object obj` parameter: you can't just replace `obj.GetType()` with `type` because if you pass in `typeof(IEnumerable<T>)` you get nothing. To get round this, test the `type` itself to see if it is a generic of `IEnumerable<>` and then its interfaces.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you very much for the discussion. I used it as a basis for the solution below, which works well for all cases that are of interest to me (IEnumerable, derived classes, etc). Thought I should share here in case anyone needs it also:

```
  Type GetItemType(object someCollection)
  {
    var type = someCollection.GetType();
    var ienum = type.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name);
    return ienum != null
      ? ienum.GetGenericArguments()[0]
      : null;
  }
```

Comment: Here's a one-liner that does all this using the null conditional operator: 

`someCollection.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name)?.GetGenericArguments()?.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit old, but I believe this method will cover all the problems and challenges stated in the comments. Credit to Eli Algranti for inspiring my work.

```cs
/// <summary>Finds the type of the element of a type. Returns null if this type does not enumerate.</summary>
/// <param name="type">The type to check.</param>
/// <returns>The element type, if found; otherwise, <see langword="null"/>.</returns>
public static Type FindElementType(this Type type)
{
   if (type.IsArray)
      return type.GetElementType();

   // type is IEnumerable<T>;
   if (ImplIEnumT(type))
      return type.GetGenericArguments().First();

   // type implements/extends IEnumerable<T>;
   var enumType = type.GetInterfaces().Where(ImplIEnumT).Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments().First()).FirstOrDefault();
   if (enumType != null)
      return enumType;

   // type is IEnumerable
   if (IsIEnum(type) || type.GetInterfaces().Any(IsIEnum))
      return typeof(object);

   return null;

   bool IsIEnum(Type t) => t == typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable);
   bool ImplIEnumT(Type t) => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static Type GetInnerGenericType(this Type type)
{
  // Attempt to get the inner generic type
  Type innerType = type.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

  // Recursively call this function until no inner type is found
  return innerType is null ? type : innerType.GetInnerGenericType();
}
```

This is a recursive function that will go depth first down the list of generic types until it gets a concrete type definition with no inner generic types.

I tested this method with this type:
`ICollection<IEnumerable<ICollection<ICollection<IEnumerable<IList<ICollection<IEnumerable<T>>>>>>>>`

which should return `T`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `typeof(T)`

**EDIT:**
Or use .GetType().GetGenericParameter() on an instantiated object if you don't have T.

Comment: True, in which case you can use .GetType(). I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for simpler situations where it's either going to be an `IEnumerable<T>` or `T` - note use of `GenericTypeArguments` instead of `GetGenericArguments()`.

```
Type inputType = o.GetType();
Type genericType;
if ((inputType.Name.StartsWith("IEnumerable"))
    && ((genericType = inputType.GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault()) != null)) {

    return genericType;
} else {
    return inputType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement on Eli Algranti's solution in that it will also work where the `IEnumerable<>` type is at any level in the inheritance tree.

This solution will obtain the element type from any `Type`. If the type is not an `IEnumerable<>`, it will return the type passed in. For objects, use `GetType`. For types, use `typeof`, then call this extension method on the result.

```
public static Type GetGenericElementType(this Type type)
{
    // Short-circuit for Array types
    if (typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        return type.GetElementType();
    }

    while (true)
    {
        // Type is IEnumerable<T>
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            return type.GetGenericArguments().First();
        }

        // Type implements/extends IEnumerable<T>
        Type elementType = (from subType in type.GetInterfaces()
            let retType = subType.GetGenericElementType()
            where retType != subType
            select retType).FirstOrDefault();

        if (elementType != null)
        {
            return elementType;
        }

        if (type.BaseType == null)
        {
            return type;
        }

        type = type.BaseType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeof(IEnumerable<Foo>)`.[`GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx)`[0]` will return the first generic argument - in this case `typeof(Foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I usually do it (via extension method):

```
public static Type GetIEnumerableUnderlyingType<T>(this T iEnumerable)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetGenericArguments()[(typeof(T)).GetTypeInfo().GetGenericArguments().Length - 1];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my unreadable Linq query expression version ..

```
public static Type GetEnumerableType(this Type t) {
    return !typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(t) ? null : (
    from it in (new[] { t }).Concat(t.GetInterfaces())
    where it.IsGenericType
    where typeof(IEnumerable<>)==it.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    from x in it.GetGenericArguments() // x represents the unknown
    let b = it.IsConstructedGenericType // b stand for boolean
    select b ? x : x.BaseType).FirstOrDefault()??typeof(object);
}
```

Note the method also takes non-generic `IEnumerable` into account, it returns `object` in this case, because it takes a `Type` rather than a concrete instance as the argument. By the way, for *x represents the unknown*, I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=6&v=YX_OxBfsvbk) insteresting, though it is irrelevant ..