# Retrieving types contained in list using reflection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting type T from IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906499/getting-type-t-from-ienumerablet)

Let's say I have a class that looks like this:

```
Public Property Name As String

Public Property Departments As List(Of Department)
```

Using reflection, I'm iterating through the properties in the class and getting their types, however, I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine that the Departments property has a List(Of **Department**). Is there a way to find out what type the list contains using reflection?

Comment: That's usually considered a bad idea even in dynamically-typed language. What reasons do you have that make it acceptable?

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172334.aspx?