# How to get a base type of a IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting type T from IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906499/getting-type-t-from-ienumerablet)

I Have a property type of `IEnumerable`

`public IEnumerable PossibleValues { get; set; }`

How can I discover the base type that it was instanced?

For example, if it was created like this:

```
PossibleValues = new int?[] { 1, 2 }
```

I want to know that type is 'int'.

Comment: @Arran, that refers to the generic version

Comment: @Arran: Not necessarily, if there is any significance in the aspect that the OP shows an array of `Nullable<int>`, but wants to retrieve `int`.

Comment: Note that there are types that implement `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`, or it could implement `IEnumerable<T>` but have all of the items in the sequence actually be sub-types of T rather than actual T instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this if you want the type of PossibleValues:

```
var type = PossibleValues.GetType().ToString(); // "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32][]"
```

Or you can do this if you want the type of an item contained in PossibleValues (assuming the array actually has values as described in your question):

```
var type = PossibleValues.Cast<object>().First().GetType().ToString(); // "System.Int32"
```

---

**EDIT**

If it's a possibility that the array may contain no items, then you'll have to do some null checking, of course:

```
var firstItem = PossibleValues.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault(o => o != null);
var type = string.Empty;
if (firstItem != null)
{
    type = firstItem.GetType().ToString();
}
```

Comment: You'll want to check that the sequence has values before pulling the first one.

Comment: That's why I stated "assuming the array actually has values".

Comment: If it doesn't have values it should probably just not come up with a type (which is still not working) but not throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks, When I have reputation enough I up your answer. I am using your second suggestion, fits right in what I needed.

Comment: @RaoniZacaron In the mean time, I think you can still accept answers regardless of reputation level (click the checkbox under the voting buttons).

Comment: @bugged87 Your check if there are any items won't work on value types, or if the enumeration simply starts with a default value.

Comment: @Servy I added some more info to my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Servy The null check does actually work for value types in this case since I'm calling `Cast<object>()`

Comment: @bugged87 My mistake, it does work just fine on a sequence of value types that starts with that type's default value.  It just doesn't work on a sequence that starts with a null value (even if there are non-null values later on).  You could add a `Where(o => o != null)` to take care of that.

Comment: @Servy Point taken. I've added a conditional statement to the FirstOrDefault() method.

Answer (score 10):

```
Type GetBaseTypeOfEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable == null)
    {
        //you'll have to decide what to do in this case
    }

    var genericEnumerableInterface = enumerable
        .GetType()
        .GetInterfaces()
        .FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

    if (genericEnumerableInterface == null)
    {
        //If we're in this block, the type implements IEnumerable, but not IEnumerable<T>;
        //you'll have to decide what to do here.

        //Justin Harvey's (now deleted) answer suggested enumerating the 
        //enumerable and examining the type of its elements; this 
        //is a good idea, but keep in mind that you might have a
        //mixed collection.
    }

    var elementType = genericEnumerableInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    return elementType.IsGenericType && elementType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
        ? elementType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
        : elementType;
}
```

This example has some limitations, which may or may not concern you in your application.  It doesn't handle the case where the type implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`.  If the type implements `IEnumerable<T>` more than once, it picks one implementation arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks, When I have reputation enough I up your answer.

Comment: I am using another answer, but the learning was good.

Comment: @RaoniZacaron I have upvoted your question, so you now have enough reputation to upvote answers (congratulations).  Don't forget to accept the answer that you are using!

Comment: @phoog at least with .NET 4.5, I'm getting an InvalidOperationException if I try to call `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on a type that isn't generic; edited to check for that before calling...

Comment: @TobyJ thanks.  I probably just assumed it would return null rather than throwing.  It's unlikely to have changed from one version to the next as that would be a breaking change.

Comment: Beautiful code and well written. I would use `typeof(IEnumerable<>).IsAssignableFrom(type)` for checking if the `type` implements the generic IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 2):

Two existing approaches are to see if the object implements `IEnumerable<T>` or to check the type of the first item in the set.  The first relies on the object actually implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, and the second only works if all of the items in the sequence are of the same derived type.

One interesting question you might ask is what types do all of the items have in common, or what is the most narrow type that is common among all of the items.

We'll start out with a simple helper method.  Given a type it will return a sequence of that type and all of it's base types.

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> getBaseTypes(Type type)
{
    yield return type;

    Type baseType = type.BaseType;
    while (baseType != null)
    {
        yield return baseType;
        baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    }
}
```

Next we'll have a method to get all of the common types for a sequence by first finding all of the most derived types, then getting all of the base types for each Type in the sequence, and finally using `intersect` to get only those items they all have in common:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> getCommonTypes(IEnumerable source)
{
    HashSet<Type> types = new HashSet<Type>();
    foreach (object item in source)
    {
        types.Add(item.GetType());
    }

    return types.Select(t => getBaseTypes(t))
        .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b));
}
```

Note that the ordering of the types in the first method is from most derived to least derived, and `Intersect` maintains ordering, so the resulting sequence will be in order from most derived to least derived.  If you want to find the most narrow type common to all of these types then you can simply use `First` on the result of this method.  (Note that since everything derives from `object` there will always be at least one type returned here unless there are no items in the original `IEnumerable`.