# Cast an object to IEnumerable<T> where I know what T is

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

I have an object which is containing an IEnumerable where T can be among a couple of Classes I have in my Data Model.

Let's say T can be either Employee or Employer. Now having a bare object, knowing that it is certainly holding an IEnumerable how Can I say which Type it is holding? Employee or Employer? Or better how can I cast or reflect the object to IEnumerable?

If I keep the type when I set the object, will it help me cast or reflect the object to what it was at first?

If I keep these

```
object source = db.Employees; //IEnumerable<Employee>
type dataType = Employee;
```

can I cast or reflect back to an IEnumerable of Employees?

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906499/getting-type-t-from-ienumerablet

Answer (score 2):

In general case you can use *Reflection*:

```
Type typeOfSource = source.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

if (typeOfSource == typeof(Employee)) {
  ...
}
else if (typeOfSource == typeof(Employer)) {
  ...
}
```

it's an *overshoot* in a simple case with *two types only*, but can be *useful* if you have a really *entangled code*.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry but I have several types and I cannot mention them because I want the code to act dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

tYou can try the `as` operator

```
var otherEmployess = source as IEnumerable<Employee>;

if(otherEmployess != null)
{
        // use otherEmployees
}
```

Alternatively you can case to `IEnumerable<Employee>` but that will throw an exception if the type is not `IEnumerable<Employee>`

Comment: I would imagine that `db.Employees` would always be an `IEnumerable<Employee>`, so why the safe cast?  I think the OP may just not know how to perform a cast in general.