# Dynamic expression on List<T>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, dynamic-linq

Given the following classes

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public List<ClassB> List { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB 
{
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I Would like to dynamically create an expression like the following

```
x => x.StringProperty == "X" && x.List.Any( y => y.IntProperty > 1 )
```

No problem for the first part (`x.StringProperty == "X"`). For the second part I have created a member expression corresponding to `x.List` and now need to

1. Create the inner lambda. To do this I need to know the type of `y` which is actually the same inner type of `x.List`
2. Call the Any method on the x.List expression

Any hint on the first point? How do I get the type T of an `IEnumerable<T>`?

**EDIT**

I have tried with the following code but it returns null unfortunately

```
//This expression will be x.List of my original sample 
MemberExpression expr = GetMemberExpression( property, pe );

Type innerType = expr.GetType()
                     .GetInterfaces()
                     .Where( t => t.IsGenericType == true && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( IEnumerable<> ) )
                     .Select( t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0] )
                     .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Can you provide the compile/runtime error?

Comment: Whats wrong with the example you provided?

Comment: I dont have any problem with my code until now. I dont know how to solve #1 at the moment. How can I get the type T of an IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: Could you should how your dynamically built expression tree looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
private static readonly MethodInfo anyT = (from x in typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                            where x.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Any) && x.IsGenericMethod
                                            let gens = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                            where gens.Length == 1
                                            let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                            where pars.Length == 2 &&
                                                pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(gens[0]) &&
                                                pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(gens[0], typeof(bool))
                                            select x).Single();

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/906513/613130
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericIEnumerables(Type type)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces()
                .Where(t => t.IsGenericType == true
                    && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
                .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
}
```

Then you can:

```
var parX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ClassA), "x");

var list = Expression.Property(parX, nameof(ClassA.List));

var listType = list.Type;
var baseType = GetGenericIEnumerables(listType).First();

var parY = Expression.Parameter(baseType, "y");

var eq = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(parX, nameof(ClassA.StringProperty)),
    Expression.Constant("X"));

var gt = Expression.GreaterThan(
    Expression.Property(parY, "IntProperty"),
    Expression.Constant(1));

var innerExpression = Expression.Lambda(gt, parY);

var any = Expression.Call(
    anyT.MakeGenericMethod(baseType),
    list,
    innerExpression);

var and = Expression.AndAlso(eq, any);

var outerExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ClassA, bool>>(and, parX);

var compiled = outerExpression.Compile();

var result = objs.Where(compiled).ToArray();
```

Note that you don't need to compile the `innerExpression`: the `outerExpression.Compile()` will do everything for you!

I'm using a modified version of [getting type T from IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906499/getting-type-t-from-ienumerablet) to find the `T` of a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks. This is very clear to me. However what I really dont know is how to get the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>` needed to create the parY in your example. The code I have is generic and build a Member expression which applies to the Enumerable of T. To let the code be generic I need to get this type dynamically.

Comment: @Lorenzo It isn't very clear what the `IEnumerable<T>` is (is `T` the `ClassA` or the `ClassB`)? And how do you receive it? Do you have an opaque `object obj` or what?

Comment: T is of type ClassB. If you look at my original  sample I wrote that I wanted to create a lambda like `x.List.Any( y => y.IntProperty > 1 )`. In this sample `IEnumerable<T>` is `x.List` and `T` is the type of the `y` inner parameter. If you look at my question edit you can see my attempt on getting the type of T. Sorry for my english

Comment: @Lorenzo I've removed the references to `ClassB` and now I'm using reflection to find it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm! :D