# Getting underlying type of an IEnumerable collection from its ISymbol

Tags: c#, .net, collections, roslyn

I have the ISymbol object for an enumerable collection and need to get the underlying type.

e.g.

```
List<int> intList;
```

I have the ISymbol for intList, and need to find the underlying type - in this case, it is int.

I tried using the code listed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8bfc1d6-fea5-4d6d-bb6d-1a16a181f0cf/getting-the-type-of-an-ienumerables-items-using-reflection?forum=netfxbcl), but seems like reflection does not work here.

Here's my code snippet:

```
private Type GetUnderlyingTypeFromEnumerable(ISymbol symbol)
{  
    Type eType = null;  
    Type[] interfaces = symbol.GetType().GetInterfaces();  
    foreach (Type i in interfaces)  
        if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(IEnumerable<>)))  
        {  
            eType = i.GetGenericArguments()[0];  
            break;  
        }  

    return eType;  
}
```

Comment: Please share the code your have tried

Comment: If you have something like: IList<int> collName... you can do - collName.GetType() and find the underlying type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting type T from IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906499/getting-type-t-from-ienumerablet)

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava I only have the ISymbol object, not the IList.

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan Updated my question with the code sample.

Comment: `ISymbol` tells you about the code. you will have to look into the documentation. `GetType` is only ever going to return the type of the `ISymbol` itself. Reflection wont help you. Roslyn has already analyzed the code

Comment: You can't mix Reflection & Roslyn symbols.  You need to use the `INamedTypeSymbol` API.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. I pried around the INamedTypeSymbol interface and found an easy way to solve this:

```
    private ITypeSymbol GetUnderlyingTypeFromEnumerable(INamedTypeSymbol symbol)
    {
        return symbol.TypeArguments.First();
    }
```